# How to get tabname in website in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I want to display Label which internal id is tabname on console.

for instance

```
console.log(<%=getCurrentAttribute('tab', 'tabname');%>);
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't do this reliably without some setup:

In your template you can have this:

```
<script>
  var currentCategory = '<%=getCurrentAttribute('sitecategory', 'itemid')%>';
  console.log(currentCategory);
</script>
```

but that will only get you the tab name if you are on a tab and not down a level on a sub-category.

I have occasionally created an empty web sit tag and then done tag substitution just at the tab level.

e.g.

```
<script>
  var currentTab = '<TOP_LEVEL>';
  console.log(currentTab);
</script>
```